# Why the sum of digits of quotient of $\frac{9}{2^n}$ is a multiple of 9?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why the sum of digits of quotient of $\frac{9}{2^n}$ is a multiple of 9?

I never noticed that till I saw a clip about it.I checked it up to few powers of $2$:

$\frac {9}{2}=4.5$ ; $4+5=9$

$\frac {9}{2^2}=2.25$ ; $2+2+5=9$

$\frac {9}{2^6}=0.140625$ ; $0+1+4+0+6+2+5=18=2\times 9$

$\frac {9}{2^{10}}=0.0087890625$ ; $8+7+8+9+6+2+5=45= 5\times 9$

This is an old finding. I tried for an analytic interpretation, got no result. I also tried using base $2$, yet nothing. Any idea or help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have

$$\frac{9}{2^n} = \frac{9(5^n)}{2^n(5^n)} = \frac{9(5^n)}{10^n} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This shows, when written in decimal, it is $9(5^n)$ with the decimal point moved $n$ digits to the left. As such, since these digits represent a multiple of $9$, the sum of all of the digits would also be a multiple of $9$.

Comment: The last fact used usually appears when trying to check if a number is divisible by $9$: you check the sum of its digits and see if you get a multiple of $9$ and if so, the original number is divisible by $9$. Here is just using this fact in the reverse order: $9$ multiplied by a number (in this case, $5^n$) is a multiple of $9$, so its digits must sum to a multiple of $9$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\frac{9}{2^{n}}=\frac{9\times 5^{n}}{10^{n}}$.

Sum of digits of $9\times 5^{n}$ is a multiple of $9$, dividing it by $10^{n}$ does not change the digits.

Comment: Hence this fact must also be true for quotient of $\frac{9}{5^n}$, am I right?

Comment: @sirous spot on!

Answer (score 0):

Writee $\frac9{2^n}=\frac{9\, 5^n}{10^n}$. Then the denominator 
is divisible by $9$. 
Accordingly the sum of ist digits is a multiple of $9$.

Comment: Schweiger, you missed $\times$ between 9 and $5^5$ on numerator.

Comment: I see. Btw. Schw*a*iger instead of _Schweiger_.